# Force users (on a mac) to log off after inactivity

Tags: macos, osx-lion, screensaver, logoff

I'm looking for a way in which I can force accounts left logged on to my Mac to auto logoff after a period of inactivity.

There is a setting built in to the operating system (Lion), that does this, but it applies to all users, and I only want to do this with certain accounts.

On Windows, I could use gpedit to force the users to use a screensaver that logs off the users. Is there something similar that I can do on Mac OS X Lion?

p.s. I'm the sole administrator on the system.

Comment: You could try going the other direction and use a program such as [Caffeine](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) to make the timeout not apply to some users, if these programs simulate user activity.

Comment: Oooh, that should do the trick nicely. If you repost as an answer I'll accept your solution.

Comment: Well, does it work? Haven't tried to use it with that option myself.

Comment: It seemed to work at first, but I've just found myself logged out due to inactivity. I think I may have had caffeine configured to only keep the system awake for a defined duration. I've now configured caffeine to work indefinitely, and am testing further, and will report back.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting logged out despite caffeine being configured to keep the system in an active state. Many thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out a way of doing this, it's a bit of a hack using shell scripts, cron and sudo, but it seems to work pretty well.

First, create a shell script `/bin/usertimeout` owned by root, chmod it to 755, and paste the following content into the file

```
#!/bin/bash

# Timeout is the number of seconds a login session can be idle before it is
# automatically logged out.
timeout=3600

if [ $(stat -f %u /dev/console) == $UID ]
then
  if [ -e /tmp/backgroundUserLogout.$UID ]
  then
    rm /tmp/backgroundUserLogout.$UID
  fi
else
  if [ ! -e /tmp/backgroundUserLogout.$UID ]
  then
    touch /tmp/backgroundUserLogout.$UID
  else
    if [ $(( `date +%s` - `stat -f %m /tmp/backgroundUserLogout.$UID || printf 0` )) -ge $(( $timeout )) ]
    then
      rm /tmp/backgroundUserLogout.$UID
      sudo /sbin/killuser
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Next, create a file `/sbin/killuser`, owned by root, chmod it to 755 and paste in the following content

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Logs out the user calling this script   

# Get the PID of the loginwindow process for the user executing this
pid=`ps -Axjc | grep ^$SUDO_USER | grep loginwindow | cut -c 14-20 | tr -d /\ /` 

# If the PID appears to be valid, kill the process
if [ $pid -gt 0 2>/dev/null ]
then
  kill -9 $pid
fi
```

Next add a crontab entry for each user that you want to be auto logged out. This would be a pain if you wanted all users to be affected, but in my case, I only require a small number of users to be logged out on idle.

```
# Crontab for user that has to be autologged out
* * * * * /bin/usertimeout
```

Note that the example above runs every minute, depending on the idle time you allow, you might want to increase this to a more suitable frequency (e.g. every 15 mins using `*/15 * * * * /bin/usertimeout`)

Now a simple mod to the sudoers file using `visudo` and you're good to go.

```
%users          ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/killuser
```

Comment: For info, the purpose of using sudo, is that `kill -9 $pid` alone isn't always enough to kill the loginwindow process. I also considered using `kill -9 -1` which would normally kill all processes belonging to the user, but according to the man pages, when you run this with sudo, it instead kills all processes on the system.

Comment: Any changes I need to do here to make this work in Ubuntu?

Comment: @DrorCohen I don't think it will, due to the use of `stat -f %u /dev/console`. It probably should be fairly trivial to fix for Ubuntu (assuming it doesn't work). If you can't get it working though, please create a new question.

Comment: can you please explain what $(stat -f %u /dev/console) == $UID is supposed to do? so I can convert it to ubuntu? thanks

Comment: OK. managed to get a copy of the stat man for mac... The problem I face now is that /dev/console in Ubuntu belongs to root...

Comment: I managed to solve my problem - see my [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/688720/how-do-i-auto-log-off-users-from-ubuntu/692346#692346). thanks for your help.